# Parsing unicode html, recognizing small text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a list of unicode objects from the google maps directions api. Here's an example of what I have:

```
[u'Keep <b>right</b> to stay on <b>E 55th St</b>',
 u'Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>S Woodlawn Ave</b>',
 u'Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>E 57th St</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Destination will be on the right</div>']
```

I want a list of the instructions, without "Destination will be on the right," so if the text is smaller, I don't want to pull it. Right now, I'm using beautiful soup and the `.get_text()` method, which just pulls all the text. How do I recognize the div style tag and skip that text?

Comment: Have you tried `tag['class']`?

Comment: just do a regex replace..

Answer (score 1):

The idea would be to remove all `div` elements with a `style` attribute and get the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '<body>Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>E 57th St</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Destination will be on the right</div></body>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for div in soup.find_all("div", style=True):
    div.extract()

print(soup.get_text())
```

Prints:

```
Turn right onto E 57th St
```